# Edit my own question to make it more attractive

Tags: discussion

Is there an accepted way to improve your question so it and its answers becomes more attractive? Is this recommended or should I just leave the smarts to SO to work out.

My question [Java 8 needs a cast while Java 7 didn't - enum.getClass/getDeclaringClass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21640002/823393) was originally called *Java 8 needs a cast while Java 7 didn't* but once answered it became clear that it was a misuse of the `Enum.getClass` method - I should have used `Enum.getDeclaringClass`.

I suspect these two methods should be highlighted as part of the question to ensure that the provided answer gets it's deserved attention.

I have added the two method names to the question title - is that a good idea?

Comment: You're describing the solution/failed approach, not the problem. *What* needs a cast?

Comment: I thought I was adding keywords that would highlight the question - *enum*, *getClass* and *getDeclaringClass* - but felt that the title may not be the best place for that for exactly the reason you point out.

Comment: People on Google are not searching for `Enum.GetDeclaringClass` if they don't already know about it.